# How to move encrypted Windows partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bitlocker, gparted

I have a 1TB SSD disk with two partitions on it. The first one (and the much bigger one) is a regular Windows partition (drive letter D), the second one (and the smaller one) is a bitlocker encrypted partition (drive letter E). I need to extend this second encrypted partition (E) at the expense of the bigger regular partition (D). The D partition is not a boot partition. I still have a second disk with a boot partition on it.

How do I go about doing this ?

I cannot use built-in Windows tools, because I need to shrink the D partition and move the E partition to the left to be able to extend it, which is not supported by Windows's built-in tools.

I have thought about using GParted on live USB, but I am not sure about the process and whether I won't break anything.

What do you think ? What are your experiences ? Or do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: Just a comment, but it seems you need to turn off Bitlocker first and then manipulate the partitions. Gparted should be able to do this. Don't forget to back up any important data first.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, GParted worked. Albeit only for moving the Bitlocker-encrypted partition to the left. To extend it, I had to go back to Windows and use the Disk Management tool.